How to remove the HD button from controls react-native-video?
How do we remove the HD button from the controls react-native-video?

Is it possible? I can not find information about it.
I tried add:
    controlsStyles={{
      hidePosition: true,
      hidePlayPause: true,
      hideForward: true,
      hideRewind: true,
      hideNext: true,
      hidePrevious: true,
      hideFullscreen: true,
      hideSeekBar: true,
      hideDuration: true,
      hideNavigationBarOnFullScreenMode: true,
      hideNotificationBarOnFullScreenMode: true,
      hideSettingButton: true,
      seekIncrementMS: 10000,
      liveLabel: "LIVE",
      hideHDButton: true,
    }}

But it not work.
